# Aligning text within progress bars

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align some text to the left and the right within some progress bars, with the percent completed written on in writing on the right side, and the title of the subject on the left. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I can't get the text over to the right while keeping some on the left, all on the same line.

I've tried aligning separate spans like this:

```
<div class="progress" style="width:40%">
    <span class="subject">Subject One</span><span class="percent">40/100</span>
</div>

/* styles */
.subject { text-align: left; }
.percent { text-align: right; }
```

but it seems inline elements don't care about their text aligning. Yet when I make one of them block, it goes to separate lines.

Here's the code snippet:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

li .completion {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  padding: 20px;
}

.completion .subject {
  text-align: left;
}

.completion .percent {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="completion" style="width: 60%"><span class="subject">Thing One</span><span class="percent">60/100</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="completion" style="width: 40%"><span class="subject">Thing Two</span><span class="percent">40/100</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

For clarification, i'd like the text to be aligned all the way to the right of the list item itself, not just within the completion div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align it all the way right you can use absolute positioning. Specify a `relative` positioning for the `li` elements, and `absolute` position for `.percent`, don't forget to place it at the right, so insert also `right: 0`. Add a right margin, if it's too close to the end of the bar.

Code snippet:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  position: relative;
}

li .completion {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  padding: 20px;
}

.completion .subject {
  text-align: left;
}

.completion .percent {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="completion" style="width: 60%"><span class="subject">Thing One</span><span class="percent">60/100</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="completion" style="width: 40%"><span class="subject">Thing Two</span><span class="percent">40/100</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:right` on the second span and delete the align.

http://jsfiddle.net/U45XR/4/

EDIT: To align it all the way right you can use css positioning. Check this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U45XR/5/.

Comment: There's no need to float `.subject`, set the float only on `.percent`, it also looks better. http://jsfiddle.net/U45XR/4/

Comment: Thanks guys. Unfortunately I explained it poorly and actually wanted the `.percent` span to be aligned all the way to the right of the list item, and not just the completion div. Thus the spans always end up on different lines, not the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I had done it that way originally, but I felt like it was bad practice to resort to absolute positioning in this situation. Am i wrong to think that?

Comment: I don't think it is a bad idea to use absolute positioning in this case.